# Retrieve value loaded dynamically from angular.js using Selenium w/ Python

Tags: python, angularjs, selenium

I am trying to grab a value from an online form that is loaded dynamically in angular.js. The value I am trying to grab is contained in this element:

```html
<input type="text" 
       ng-disabled="jMrId" 
       class="form-control 
       ng-pristine 
       ng-valid" 
       id="work-email" 
       name="work-email" 
       ng-model="mR.jWorkEmail" 
       ng-trim="false" 
       ng-blur="validateWorkEmail()">
```

I have tried, and no surprise, failed, to grab the text via `.text` and `.get_attribute('innerText')`

I've read a bit about Pytractor, but knowing that it has not been maintained for some years, I am wondering if it could still be applicable to this purpose with Python 3.8 and Selenium 3.141.0.

Likewise, regarding Pytractor, I have seen several posts asking about *inputting* text into an Angular.js form, but I haven't come across any posts about *retrieving* data from an Angular.js form.

How might I get the dynamically loaded text, that is never displayed explicitly in the code, with or without Pytractor?

Answer (score 0):

To get the value from `input` textbox you need use `value` attribute.

`element.get_attribute('value')`

where element is

```
element=driver.find_element_by_id("work-email")
```